# Hide/Show many views onScroll RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have layout like that:

[image]

I would like to implement that functionality: When user ScrollDown `RecyclerView` two things which he see are `Toolbar` and `FilterPanel`. The `title` and `image` is hidden, when he scroll up till to the beggining of the `recyclerview` the `title` and `image` appear.

There is my `HiddingScrollListener`:

```
public abstract class HidingScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    private static final float HIDE_THRESHOLD = 10;
    private int scrolledDistance = 0;
    private boolean controlsVisible = true;

    public HidingScrollListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


        if (scrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
            onHide();
            controlsVisible = false;
            scrolledDistance = 0;
        } else if (scrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
            onShow();
            controlsVisible = true;
            scrolledDistance = 0;
        }

        if((controlsVisible && dy>0) || (!controlsVisible && dy<0)) {
            scrolledDistance += dy;
        }


    }


    public abstract void onShow();
    public abstract void onHide();

}
```

And my implementation of this `listener` in `activity`:

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onHide() {
                mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
```

I don't know how to catch when `RecyclerView` is in the beggining and how to show `title` and `image` in this case. And I have a problem: How to pin `FilterPanel` under the `Toolbar` when I scroll down?

Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `CoordinatorLayout` from the android design support library.
This layout coordinates between it's children events, most commonly scroll events. Here is a tutorial: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout